# Wine like for Android

Tags: android, symbian

I am pondering the idea of a Wine-ish compatibility layer on Android.
The idea is to run Symbian apps on it as both OSes share ARM hardware.

I have no knowledge of Symbian but I think that given the hardware capabilities of Android devices this could be done with less effort than Wine's windows emulation.

What would be the most significant difference to overcome in this emulator? (threading, storage, ...)

Comment: WINE does not emulate Windows. It actually stands for Wine Is Not an Emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is not going to be code execution, but the API's to do things like graphics, interact with hardware, accept input, etc.  If you have documentation of the original and android has the capability, API translation layers would be possible.

But android's security model outright prevents a number of things that are possible on other phone platforms, and combined with it's "java apis only" allows only inefficient means of doing things that can be done more efficiently on others.

This is of course all about application-level emulation/api translation.  If you are willing to modify the android platform itself, supporting just about anything else for which you have documentation (and licensing?) within the hardware capability of the device should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware capabilities of a device have nothing to do with complexity of an emulator to be hosted. It depends on Symbian's design and complexity.

And, even more, licencing. Even if one could make a Symbian emulator for Android, its legality would be questioned.

It's difficult to answer your question in detail, but since Symbian is open sourced (and Android too), if you've got the time, it shouldn't be too hard to see what sets them apart.

Comment: Hardware has a little to do with the speed of the adapted code. If the compatibility layer is not thin enough to make 1:1 adaptations then the glue code might eat some of the cpu bandwidth. 
As I said,I do not know anything about Symbian and its internals - that's why I asked this question. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @Daniel: true, but your statement "given the hardware capabilities of Android devices this could be done with less effort than Wine's windows emulation" doesn't hold. You can have a PC with 50Ghz and still it wouldn't be any easier to make a Playstation 3 emulator for it.

Comment: CellBE vs. x86 is not the same as ARM v7 (Android's goldfish) vs. ARM v7 (OMAP/...). You still have a valid point here. The idea is that the code that has no 1:1 mapping between Symbian and Android has to be written - and this code should work as fast as possible - hence the need for a faster hardware.

Answer (score 1):

QT is used for the latest symbian OS, and has been ported to Android, you could write apps in QT build for each platform

Comment: For S^3 yes, this is the way to go. What if you want to run an older app from S60 or earlier models? There was no QT then... One example I have in mind is Garmin MobileXT - excellent application with discontinued support on WinMo and Symbian. It would be great to be able to runit on a newer phone.

Comment: thats true, like I said QT is used in the latest symbian OS :)

Answer (score 1):

the problem for writing an emulatir are variouss.

If the Symbian apps are written in in an interpreter language like Basic or similar then an emulator couldn't be too difficult to write. I did such stuff once to make the same code run on linux and windows, and I used a translation API for all calles coming from the software directed to UI, input/output.

I wound guess that the UI capabilities of Symbian are a subset of the Android functions so it would be not too difficult to write a WINE alike thing or an interpreter that runs the Symbian code on different hardware - IF it is only in high language.

But be aware there could be some machine code in the appps and that is processor specific. Most of the Android tabs nowadays run on Tegra, Tegra2 or (soon) on Tegra3, some may run on StrongArm or Arm, some may run on Intel Atom (x86 architechture), so this might get more or less impossible if the CPU isn't binary compatible like ARM / ATOM. Then you need to emulate the CPU as well and that might eat so much performance that you need a 4-5 times stronger machine to run that stuff smoothly.

It won't be too difficult to crack Android to execute Linux-alike binaries, but for sure this "mod" will affect the ability to use or download stuff from regular appstores.

With some apps you might have even more headache, e.G. my MP3 player from Korea runs on Strongarm, but it also executes Flash games from various sources. When there is no Flash player - and Google announced something like dropping support for Adobe Flash - it won't be usable.

The "most wanted" is obviously the Ovi Maps, probably that stuff could be easily converted to another app having offline navigation capability :-) People wrote "Gaia" some years ago, an open source viewer for Google Earth (and later forced to give up) so it can't bee too difficult to realize at least this.